# Shortcut to string in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-snippets

When using Visual Studio console applications I often use the following line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
```

Is there a way of setting up a short-cut key in Visual Studio so that I don't need to type this every time?

There are probably other lines of code I regularly use for one reason or another that a short-cut feature would be beneficial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define yourself a [code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b%28VS.80%29.aspx). [Creating Our Own Snippets Using Visual Studio 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226359/Creating-Our-Own-Snippets-Using-Visual-Studio-2010) is a cool article for this.

For `Console.Writeline()` method, write `cw` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.

[image]

Comment: pressing tab once is enough

Comment: If you write only `cw`, you should press twice. If you write `cw` and click on it, once is enough.

Comment: I'll follow your link. p.s that colour scheme is ace - is it totally customised? or is it a set style (not sure if VS has those?)

Comment: For the color schemes look at http://studiostyl.es/ and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Save this in (filename).snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CodeSnippets
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
      <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
          <Title>cwe</Title>
          <Shortcut>cwe</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
          <Code Language="CSharp">
            <![CDATA[Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");]]>
          </Code>
        </Snippet>
      </CodeSnippet>
    </CodeSnippets>
```

Next choose tools-> code snippet manager... , click import, choose your file and add.

Now if you type `cwe` while you coding click Tab.

Comment: +1 I like this. Do I Save `(filename).snippet` anywhere in my local drive before importing - or save it in a specific directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you just often need to use `Console.WriteLine()`, you can type <kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: I specifically want bthis snippet aswell `("press [enter] to exit")` ...I'll follow Sonar's link